# MATLAB - Creating a repeating textscan process which runs until an entire file has been dealt with

Tags: matlab, repeat, textscan

I'll start out by saying that I'm something of a Matlab newbie so I apologise if this question has been asked before but I have been unable to find the answer I need.

I'm working on a code to process some large Rainfall Radar files (5-20GB), I have arranged the code to read the data in 24 hour blocks and then remove some unnecessary points. As below:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

fileID=fopen('Selkirk_15min_2008.csv');

% Open relevant Hyrad Rainfall Radar Output File.

C_Header=textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s',12,'delimiter',',');

% Read the file's header section - first 12 row in standard output file.

C_GridDataCheck=textscan(fileID,'%s %s %d',1230,'delimiter',',');

% Read the data coverage section of the file - number of rows eg 1230 is
% equal to the number of grid points used.

C_DataHeader=textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s',1,'delimiter',',');

% Read the column headers of the main data array.

formatSpec='%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s';
N=118080;
C_Read=textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N,'delimiter',',');

% Load the first 118,080 rows of data (1230 = 1 x 15 Min Timestep across
% whole catchment. 1230x4 = 4,920. 4,920x24 = 118,080. Hence this sample
% size is equal to one 24 hour period. 

C_Day1=horzcat(C_Read{1,1},C_Read{1,2},C_Read{1,3},C_Read{1,4},C_Read{1,5},C_Read{1,6},C_Read{1,7},C_Read{1,8});

% Combine data arrays created by textscan into one matrix

load('SelkirkNRP.mat')

% % Load list of non-relevant grid numbers for use.

C_Day1(any(ismember(C_Day1(:,1),SelkirkNRP),2),:)=[];

% % Check first column against list of non-relevant grid points and remove
% % all non-relevant rows

disp('24 Hour period loaded and non-relevant grid points removed')

% ------------------SECOND 24 HOUR PERIOD--------------------------------

C_Read=textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N,'delimiter',',');
% NB - 2000 Days between March 1st, 2008 and August 22nd, 2013
% No of Obs Per day = 118,080
% No of Obs in Dataset = 236,160,000 (rows - each row is 8 cells)
% Load the next 118,080 lines of data 

C_Day2=horzcat(C_Read{1,1},C_Read{1,2},C_Read{1,3},C_Read{1,4},C_Read{1,5},C_Read{1,6},C_Read{1,7},C_Read{1,8});

%Combine data arrays created by textscan into one matrix

C_Day2(any(ismember(C_Day2(:,1),SelkirkNRP),2),:)=[];

% % Check first column against list of non-relevant grid points and remove
% % all non-relevant rows

disp('24 Hour period loaded and non-relevant grid points removed')

%------------------THIRD 24 HOUR PERIOD-----------------------------------

C_Read=textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N,'delimiter',',');

% Load the next 118,080 lines of data 

C_Day3=horzcat(C_Read{1,1},C_Read{1,2},C_Read{1,3},C_Read{1,4},C_Read{1,5},C_Read{1,6},C_Read{1,7},C_Read{1,8});

% Combine data arrays created by textscan into one matrix

C_Day3(any(ismember(C_Day3(:,1),SelkirkNRP),2),:)=[];

% % Check first column against list of non-relevant grid points and remove
% % all non-relevant rows

disp('24 Hour period loaded and non-relevant grid points removed')
```

I hope this code makes clear what I'm trying to achieve. If not feel free to ask.

Essentially, what I need is to make this section of the code:

```
% ------------------SECOND 24 HOUR PERIOD--------------------------------

C_Read=textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N,'delimiter',',');
% NB - 2000 Days between March 1st, 2008 and August 22nd, 2013
% No of Obs Per day = 118,080
% No of Obs in Dataset = 236,160,000 (rows - each row is 8 cells)
% Load the next 118,080 lines of data 

C_Day2=horzcat(C_Read{1,1},C_Read{1,2},C_Read{1,3},C_Read{1,4},C_Read{1,5},C_Read{1,6},C_Read{1,7},C_Read{1,8});

%Combine data arrays created by textscan into one matrix

C_Day2(any(ismember(C_Day2(:,1),SelkirkNRP),2),:)=[];

% % Check first column against list of non-relevant grid points and remove
% % all non-relevant rows

disp('24 Hour period loaded and non-relevant grid points removed')
```

Repeat until the entire file has been processed. I think this should be about 2000 iterations. Also, I know this code is very rough and ready at the moment and not all that elegant, any helpful comments for  a newbie will be gratefully received.

Hoping you can help.

Best

Sam

Update:

After digging this issued was solved and simplified with a For Loop, example code below.

```
clear all; close all; clc;

fileID=fopen('Selkirk_15min_2008.csv');

% Open relevant Hyrad Rainfall Radar Output File.

C_Header=textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s',12,'delimiter',',');

% Read the file's header section - first 12 row in standard output file.

C_GridDataCheck=textscan(fileID,'%s %s %d',1230,'delimiter',',');

% Read the data coverage section of the file - number of rows eg 1230 is
% equal to the number of grid points used.

C_DataHeader=textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s',1,'delimiter',',');

% Read the column headers of the main data array.

formatSpec='%s %f %f %f %f %s %s %f';
N=118080;

load('SelkirkNRP.mat')

% Load list of non-relevant grid numbers for use.

for i=1:1

C_Read=textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N,'delimiter',',');

% Load the first 118,080 rows of data (1230 = 1 x 15 Min Timestep across
% whole catchment. 1230x4 = 4,920. 4,920x24 = 118,080. Hence this sample
% size is equal to one 24 hour period. 

C_Data=horzcat(C_Read{1,1},C_Read{1,2},C_Read{1,3},C_Read{1,4},C_Read{1,5},C_Read{1,6},C_Read{1,7},C_Read{1,8});

% Combine data arrays created by textscan into one matrix

C_Data(any(ismember(C_Data(:,1),SelkirkNRP),2),:)=[];

% Check first column against list of non-relevant grid points and remove
% all non-relevant rows

C_DataMatrix=str2double(C_Data);

% Convert Cell Array to Matrix for writing to CSV

csvwrite(['Day ' num2str(i) ' Data'], C_DataMatrix)

%Write to CSV

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but it seem all you need is a [loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/programming-basics.html#programming-loops) statement ([for](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/for.html) or [while](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/while.html)).

Comment: @pseudoDust Yes, a For Loop has solved the issue, a little more digging turned this up, I was just returning to update the thread. Thanks for the advice.